# MySQL insert adds rows with id's that shouldn't exist

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm facing something weird here, i have a database table from which i select certain rows, in total ~43.000, these fetched rows contain a field called cns_id (note, this is not the primary key/auto increment field), and are inserted into a diffrent table.

Although everything seems to run fine, each time i end up with 94 inserted rows that have a cns_id of 2147483647, an id which doesn't even exist inside the table from which i fetch the data.

Below is the stored procedure i'm using, although this issue also happens when i perform the same kind of query with Eloquent.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE FillCnsGroupWithRates
(
    IN groupId INT(10)
)
BEGIN
    SET @var1 = groupId;
INSERT INTO 
     cns_group_rates 
    (
         cns_id,
        other_cns_id,
        ppc,
        pps,
        max_price,
        notes,
        cns_group_id,
        created_at,
        updated_at
    )
    SELECT 
        cns_id,
        other_cns_id,
        ppc,
        pps,
        max_price,
        notes,
        @var1,
        now(),
        now()
    FROM 
        cns_rates
    WHERE 
        cns_id NOT LIKE '319%'
    AND
        client_id IS NULL
    AND
         subordinates IS NULL
     AND
        valid_from IS NULL;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I think you may have an overflow. How is cns_id defined in these 2 tables?

Comment: 2147483647 is max_int for a signed 32bit int, so yeah... most likely an overflow. cns_rates.cns_id is either a bigint or unsigned, whereas cns_group_rates.cns_id is signed and/or a normal int.

Comment: You were completely right, i totally forgot to check wether both tables had the same field settings, it turns out the cns_rates.cns_id was a varchar(20) (not my database so don't blame me :P), while cns_group_rates.cns_id was an int(10), i changed that and now it's sorted!